# DocuSign and Salesforce Communities Question

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi, salesforce-communities

Is there a way where the Docusign app can run in Salesforce Communities, and a communities member can self-service to send themselves an envelope for signature?

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign eSignature for Salesforce doesn't officially support Communities use.

One potential solution for self-service would be to direct the community member to a PowerForm (general info here: https://www.docusign.com/features-and-benefits/features/powerforms) to have them fill out an envelope. You can then set up DocuSign Connect to writeback that envelope's info: https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/How-to-configure-a-PowerForm-to-writeback-to-specific-Salesforce-records